# Trigger numeric keyboard for input in Android/IOS without HTML5

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, jquery-plugins, numeric

I've searched through the websites that I found the following.

Using html5, we can trigger numeric keyboard with effortless like following,

```
<input type='tel' />
<input type='number'/>
<input type='text' pattern='some pattern' /> (This will work in IOS and not in android)
```

But I am using the [autoNumeric](https://github.com/BobKnothe/autoNumeric) plugin to format/restrict the user input if as digits.
**As per the documentation of autoNumeric plugin (http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/),
autoNumeric won't work if input type='tel/number**' . I tried and yes it doesn't work.

- If I go with the HTML5 and removing autoNumeric, will reflect in the way that my application won't be user friendly. To make it user friendly I need to do more code changes (It should be researched perfectly before start :-( ).
- If I go with autoNumeric, then my application won't be user friendly in MOBILE.
- If I go with another plugin instead of autoNumeric and that support HTML5, then I need to rework with whole project and testing time will take more cost.

Here my requirement is,

How to **enable/trigger numeric keyboard** in mobile/ipad/iphone **without html5** ?

Or

Is there any jquery plugin to **enable/trigger numeric keyboard** in mobile/ipad/iphone **without html5 and with autoNumeric js ([autonumeric js](https://github.com/BobKnothe/autoNumeric))**?

Comment: You should consider the html5 version for mobiles, and perhaps fall  back to a version using your plugin for desktops.

Comment: If am right, you are saying to detect dynamically and load appropriate the input and jquery plugin. Right ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the documentation, `Version 1.9.19` added support for `<input type='tel' />`

So, why not use that?

Comment: Do they documented it ?

Comment: Hi but they've mentioned like "Type must best set to "text" to have autoNumeric function properly" :-( . check the documentation http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/

Comment: Yup, they have mentioned in the update log of that version. Its on the doc page. Scroll below and see

Comment: Yes, but I've seen like in the known issues as "Type must best set to "text" to have autoNumeric function properly"

Answer (score 4):

[Official workarounds](https://github.com/BobKnothe/autoNumeric/issues/125) from *autoNumeric.js* are

1. `<input type="text" pattern="\d*">`  Currently works on iOS only
2. `<input type="tel" pattern="\d*">` Should work on most mobile browsers - on android devices you may get the pause and wait buttons.

If you need decimal digits, you may modify the pattern to `[\d\.]*`.